# Update UIProgressView from network

Tags: swift, uiprogressview

I use Xcode 10 and Swift 4.2

in viewDidload () of a UIViewController, I declare an observer:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(OtherFunctionsViewController.dataImportExportFunc), name: .ImportExportdata, object: nil)
}
```

From the network, I receive a message (based on .ImportExportdata name) that increases a float value called  ProgressLevel from 0.0 to 1.0

I have declared this value to be followed by IOS, and it works. It prints correctly the value that will be updated

```
@IBOutlet weak var OtherFuncProgressView: UIProgressView!
var ProgressLevel : Float = 0.0 {
    willSet // "name" is ABOUT TO CHANGE
    {
        print("ProgressLevel WILL be set...")
        print("from current value: \(ProgressLevel)")
        print("to new value: \(newValue).\n")
        DispatchQueue.global(qos: DispatchQoS.QoSClass.userInteractive).async
            {
                DispatchQueue.main.async
                    {
                        print("dispatch queue main")
                        self.OtherFuncProgressView.setProgress(Float(self.ProgressLevel), animated: true)
                        self.OtherFuncProgressView.setNeedsDisplay()
                }
        }
    }
}
```

ProgressLevel is correctly printed, but the progressView is never updated on screen.

### What is wrong?

Thanks for your answer

I change my code according to your proposal as follows:

```
    var ProgressLevel : Float = 0.0

    {
        willSet // "name" is ABOUT TO CHANGE
        {
            print("ProgressLevel WILL be set...")
            print("from current value: \(ProgressLevel)")
            print("to new value: \(newValue).\n")
//            DispatchQueue.global(qos: DispatchQoS.QoSClass.userInteractive).async
//                {
                    DispatchQueue.main.async
                        {
                            print("dispatch queue main value \(newValue)")
//                            self.OtherFuncProgressView.setProgress(Float(self.ProgressLevel), animated: true)
                            self.OtherFuncProgressView.setProgress(Float(newValue), animated: true)

                            self.OtherFuncProgressView.setNeedsDisplay()
                    }
//            }
        }
}
```

I got:
ProcessImportFile:  file:///Users/guydesbief/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/17DA59AA-430F-4395-B2F3-FF2A81EEB429/data/Containers/Data/Application/91B3BA10-45C1-4090-A401-5CDA03EED8C8/tmp/2019-2-21_2018-2-19_Mois.csv
2019-02-21 11:18:22.755903+0100 SolarPanelSurveyIos[85928:4363118] razImport Done
ProgressLevel WILL be set...
from current value: 0.0
to new value: 0.0.

2019-02-21 11:18:22.758389+0100 SolarPanelSurveyIos[85928:4363118] Statistic WindowController file Stream OK
2019-02-21 11:18:22.760550+0100 SolarPanelSurveyIos[85928:4363118] no buffer!
dispatch queue main value 0.0
2019-02-21 11:18:22.760800+0100 SolarPanelSurveyIos[85928:4363118] Statistic WindowController No more data read from file!
2019-02-21 11:18:22.761242+0100 SolarPanelSurveyIos[85928:4363118] Field Header: Import Record  Ended with 
 char Nbfields = 4 , Current record: 0
2019-02-21 11:18:22.761342+0100 SolarPanelSurveyIos[85928:4363118] Import ended 40 records, 38 Maxrecords

ProgressLevel WILL be set...
from current value: 0.0
to new value: 0.05263158.

ProgressLevel WILL be set...
from current value: 0.05263158
to new value: 0.13157895.

ProgressLevel WILL be set...
from current value: 0.13157895
to new value: 0.21052632.

ProgressLevel WILL be set...
from current value: 0.21052632
to new value: 0.28947368.

ProgressLevel WILL be set...
from current value: 0.28947368
to new value: 0.36842105.

ProgressLevel WILL be set...
from current value: 0.36842105
to new value: 0.4473684.

ProgressLevel WILL be set...
from current value: 0.4473684
to new value: 0.5263158.

ProgressLevel WILL be set...
from current value: 0.5263158
to new value: 0.6052632.

ProgressLevel WILL be set...
from current value: 0.6052632
to new value: 0.68421054.

ProgressLevel WILL be set...
from current value: 0.68421054
to new value: 0.7631579.

ProgressLevel WILL be set...
from current value: 0.7631579
to new value: 0.84210527.

ProgressLevel WILL be set...
from current value: 0.84210527
to new value: 0.92105263.

ProgressLevel WILL be set...
from current value: 0.92105263
to new value: 1.0.

2019-02-21 11:18:23.631275+0100 SolarPanelSurveyIos[85928:4363118] Temps d'exécution: 871867

dataImportExportFunc No more datas number of records : 0 / 39.000000 execTime: 0.8719

dispatch queue main value 0.05263158

dispatch queue main value 0.13157895

dispatch queue main value 0.21052632

dispatch queue main value 0.28947368

dispatch queue main value 0.36842105

dispatch queue main value 0.4473684

dispatch queue main value 0.5263158

dispatch queue main value 0.6052632

dispatch queue main value 0.68421054

dispatch queue main value 0.7631579

dispatch queue main value 0.84210527

dispatch queue main value 0.92105263

dispatch queue main value 1.0

Dispatch queue is emptied only at the end of process, and I would like to empty it in real time
Any suggestions are welcome

Comment: Try just using the `DispatchQueue.main.async ` instead of nesting it inside the `DispatchQueue.global(qos: DispatchQoS.QoSClass.userInteractive).async `

Comment: what do you need this `self.OtherFuncProgressView.setNeedsDisplay()` line for, anyway?

Answer (score 0):

`willSet` is called before the value is updated, so you are better off using `newValue` inside the closure:

```
var progressLevel: Float = 0.0 {
    // "name" is ABOUT TO CHANGE
    willSet {
        print("ProgressLevel WILL be set...")
        print("from current value: \(progressLevel)")
        print("to new value: \(newValue).\n")
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            print("dispatch queue main")
            self.OtherFuncProgressView.setProgress(Float(newValue, animated: true)
            self.OtherFuncProgressView.setNeedsDisplay()
        }
    }
}
```